# Passing ng-repeat object and array to function using _.without

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, lodash

I'm attempting to create dry functions to add and remove items from arrays. Useful for editable tables. This entails passing an object and array to a function using lodash's `_.whithout` so that whenever a row needs to be removed from a table (or array in general) just pass the object to remove and the array to be removed from.

**The issue**

Defining the array in the function works fine. The object is removed and the DOM is updated. Passing the array as a parameter does not. The object is removed but the DOM is not updated.

**Hypothesis**

Angular is unbinding the array.

---

Any idea how to keep the array parameter bound?

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/earzu30v/4/)

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<table ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input ng-model="newItem" type="number">
      </th>
      <th>
        <button type="button" ng-click="addItemDef(newItem)">Add - Array Defined</button>
      </th>
      <th>
        <button type="button" ng-click="addItemUndef(newItem, items)">Add - Array Undefined</button>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
      <td>{{item.value}}</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" ng-click="removeItemDef(item)">Remove - Array Defined</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" ng-click="removeItemUndef(item, items)">Remove - Array Undefined</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    value: 5
  }];

  $scope.addItemDef = function(item) {
    foo = {
        value: item
      }
      //console.log(foo)
    $scope.items.push(foo);
    console.log($scope.items)
  };
  $scope.addItemUndef = function(item, array) {
    thing = {
      value: item
    }
    array.push(thing);
    console.log($scope.items)
  };

  $scope.removeItemDef = function(obj) {
    console.log('Before')
    console.log($scope.items)
      //    var itemWithId = _.find($scope.items, function(item) {
      //      return item.value == obj.value;
      //    });
    $scope.items = _.without($scope.items, obj);
    console.log('After')
    console.log($scope.items)
  };
  //This is the function that does not work
  $scope.removeItemUndef = function(obj, array) {
    console.log('Before')
    console.log(array)
    console.log($scope.items)
      //    var itemWithId = _.find(array, function(item) {
      //      return item.value == obj.value;
      //    });
    array = _.without(array, obj);
    console.log('After')
    console.log(array)
    console.log($scope.items)
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because [lodash creates a new array](https://lodash.com/docs#without) when calling `_.without`.

Next, you assign the copy to the parameter of the function which has no effect on the argument passed in; you simply overwrite the parameter reference inside the function scope with the new copy from `_.without`.

```
// this can't work:
$scope.removeItemUndef = function(obj, array) {
   console.log('Before', array, $scope.items);
   array = _.without(array, obj); // << overwriting reference with no effect
   console.log('After', array, $scope.items);
};
```

The solution is to leave the array passed intact and modify the inside of that array, using `Array.splice`.

```
// this however will work:
$scope.removeItemUndef = function(obj, array) {
   console.log('Before', array, $scope.items);
   var result = _.without(array, obj);
   // remove the current content, and replace with result's content:
   Array.prototype.splice.apply(array, [0, array.length].concat(result));
   console.log('After', array, $scope.items);
};
```

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/earzu30v/5/)

The reason for using `Array.prototyp.splice.apply(array, ...)` rather than `array.splice(...)` is that splice accepts spread arguments instead of an array. By using the `.apply` trick, we can pass an array instead.

Comment: So if I understand that correctly in order to maintain the binding, we're splicing everything out of the bound array and filling it with the result of _.without. That's an interesting solution. I had forgotten that Lodash returns a new array.

Comment: @davidcapatch, correct. The key is that you need to modify the passed in array (or overwritte the existing `$scope.items` with the copy, which was already working in your `.removeItemDef`).